# BSOD issue on Abit IP 35 Pro

Tags: drivers, raid, crash, bsod

I have a custom built PC with the following specs -

1. Abit IP35 Pro
2. 4GB Nvidia SLI DDR2 RA
3. Nvidia 9800 GTX PCI-E Graphics Card
4. 1 x Asus DVD drive
5. 4 x 500GB hard drives configured in RAID 5
6. 1 x 1TB drive outside of the RAID

I have got an annoying issue where the machine Blue screens all the time. At first I thought it was a Windows 8 issue perhaps as I was running Win 8 RC. I have just install fresh Windows 7 and I still get a BSOD. The BSOD seems to come after the PC has been up for about 20-30 minutes in windows.

Because of all the unexpected shutdowns my RAID is now in a degraded state and needs rebuilding, it actually rebooted whilst rebuilding so I now I'm worried if it keeps happening I'm going to lose data on my RAID!

I'm starting to think it could be a faulty memory stick so plan to run a memtest tonight and will report back, in the meantime though is there anything else anyone can think of?

Also any tips on BSOD debugging so I can try to get to the bottom of what piece of hardware is causing it?

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Check the cpu temperature in bios. Also check by removing graphics card and running on on board graphics. Remove ram and clean it and insert it again.

Comment: Ok thanks I did wonder if it was perhaps overheating - have the cpu fan set to lowest at the moment. Sadly can't use on-board graphics as the mobo doesn't have it. Will run the memtest if comes back fine then will remove the ram and clean. Could it be HDD related too? my main 1tb drives seems to have started clicking and taking a while to spin up (this is the one outside of the RAID).

Comment: Can be.. Check after removing hard disk.

Comment: Check one by one......